# Class not found error when using JWT library in PHP

Tags: php, jwt

I need to perform various jwt actions in php, such as decoding, validating, etc

This involves downloading php libraries

One that I have picked is adocore/jwt

I installed it with no errors using:

```
composer require adhocore/jwt
```

I have a really simple snippet to see if I can create the object

```
<?php
  ini_set('display_errors', 1);
  ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);

  require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

  use Ahc\Jwt\JWT;

  // Instantiate with key, algo, maxAge and leeway.
  $jwt = new JWT('secret', 'HS256', 3600, 10);    
?>
```

Posting into this page gives the error

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>: Class 'Ahc\Jwt\JWT' not found in
<b>/PATH/myfile.php</b> on line <b>11</b><br />
```

Any idea what I have done wrong?

Paul

Comment: Have you tried doing `composer dump-autoload`?

Answer (score 0):

add this below file base on your file path in my case it is working

```
require_once 'jwt/src/BeforeValidException.php';
require_once 'jwt/src/ExpiredException.php';
require_once 'jwt/src/SignatureInvalidException.php';
require_once 'jwt/src/JWT.php';
```

use \Firebase\JWT\JWT